# Failed to create JVM after trying to set more memory for Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to set my memory on 4GB using the command `-Xmx4g` from `Help->Edit VME Options` but when I try to open the `Android Studio` I get the error mentioned in the title.

> If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer >System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
>   Failed to create JVM. JVM Path ...\jre.

I've already tried some other answers from the same questions, but nothing worked for me

Tried:

> Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
>
> Open it with notepad. some times it will not be editable so give
>   administrative permission and change the following attributes:
>
> -Xmx512m to -Xmx256m
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=250m to -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
>
> Or change:
>
> -Xmx750m to -Xmx512m
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=350m to -XX:MaxPermSize=250m

But in my `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions` or `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

I don't have the `-XX:MaxPermSize`, only the `-Xmx's` which I already tried to change but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work by tracking down the config file created when trying to change the memory. `C:\Users\(pc-name)\.AndroidStudio\config\studio.exe.vmoptions`. Ive deleted that file and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

> Workarounds for this situation:
>
> 1. Run with **-XX:-UseCompressedOops** (keeping in mind that you would lose the performance benefit that comes with enabling CompressedOops).
>      This will instruct the JVM to run without the Compressed Oops feature
>      and it would not try to fit the Java Heap in the first 4GB of heap.
> 2. Keep the CompressedOops and set the base of the Java Heap with the JVM option **-XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=n** to specify the address where the
>      Java Heap should start from. If you are running out of native memory,
>      set it to a higher address so that there is enough room available for
>      the native mallocs, and if Java Heap is getting exhausted then set it
>      to a lower value. And if you need java heap to be allocated beyond 4GB
>      or 32GB then HeapBaseMinAddress should be set to a value so that
>      HeapBaseMinAddress + heap size > 4GB or 32GB. The default value of
>      HeapBaseMinAddress on most of the platforms is 2GB.
>
> Let's run a simple test program on solaris-sparc 10 and solaris-x64 11
>   and see where the Java Heap is placed on these platforms when using
>   CompressedOops.

For the work procedure refer the below link

https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/running-on-a-64bit-platform-and-still-running-out-of-memory

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste from a blog you should be clearer about what is your own work and what is a quote.